# Injecting multiple firestore apps breaks in production mode

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Basically I need to use multiple firebase apps to distinguish some data that goes in different firestore projects. Injecting by myself has been working fine until I deployed to the production environment. I have found a workaround by switching the configuration of angular.json to

```
"optimization": false
```

Obviously this causes other problems which increases the bundling size for example.

```
export const firstAppName = 'first';
export const secondAppName = 'second';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
    useFactory: AngularFirestoreFirstFactory,
    deps: [PLATFORM_ID, NgZone]
})
export class AngularFirestoreFirst extends AngularFirestore {}

export function AngularFirestoreFirstFactory(platformId: object, zone: NgZone) {
    return new AngularFirestore(environment.firstAppName, firstAppName, true, null, platformId, zone, null);
}
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
    useFactory: AngularFirestoreSecondFactory,
    deps: [PLATFORM_ID, NgZone]
})
export class AngularFirestoreSecond extends AngularFirestore {}

export function AngularFirestoreSecondFactory(platformId: object, zone: NgZone) {
    return new AngularFirestore(environment.secondAppName, secondAppName, false, null, platformId, zone, null);
}
```

This works fine in localhost on `ng serve`. Problems start coming out when I deploy in production or I run the local server with `ng serve --prod`

TypeError: firestore is not a function

What makes it different in dependency injection with optimization: true to change the behavior.

[image: firestore is not a function]

Comment: Did you try `import * as firebase from 'firebase'; import 'firebase/firestore';`?

Comment: `import 'firebase/firestore';`

Actually worked. I guess the AOT compiler is getting its imports differently, that is the only reason I can understand why it worked in local but not --prod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the firebase core library does not include the firestore library innately. To fix you problem:

```
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

Comment: The wierdest part for me is that I have this same config for another project and it works fine in --prod mode without the
`import 'firebase/firestore';`


So i guess I must have some other config code creating this problem, which is scary to me. Thank you for you answer.